# Token exchange in Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server, token-exchange

The problem I am trying to solve is where we have multiple IDPs coming into our application edge from various authentication sources. What I want to do is to use token exchange to swap this token, for a token which can be understood at any level of our micro service architecture. I envision the token will simply be for identity only. The overhead of trying to build multiple IDPs into every component within our system is proving a big challenge.

Can you advise if the token exchange mechanism is suitable for this? At least at RFC level it appears to be suitable.

We have been experimenting with spring auth server for the last few months.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You would need to build such a Security Token Service (STS) yourself because Spring Authorization Server only knows about tokens it issues. Have you considered federating login instead of using token exchange?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I looked at federating login, but I do not want to manage anything to do with redirects or logins. The idea was for a request that comes to the auth server for any number of known identity providers, assume there is already a valid authenticated token, and then only the auth server can validate those tokens and claims, and then generate a token which can be used across multiple services that dont need to know about the original identity provider.

Comment: I believe what you're describing is an STS. It is a product feature. There are likely many products that do this, or you can implement it yourself but it is not something that SAS can do for you.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2024/03/19/token-exchange-support-in-spring-security-6-3-0-m3 describes a scenario where user-service (RS1) calls message-service (RS2) which requires access tokens (AT) with a different audience. Prior to calling RS2, RS1 exchanges ATs for RS2-suitable ones. RS1 is configured as a client of an Authorisation Server (AS) that exchanges tokens.
Couldn't SAS help here? For an external request with an external AT, an internal service, client of an internal AS, would request from it the exchange of the external AT for an internal one, allowing it to call internal services.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Is it by design that SAS only knows about tokens it issues or could external-for-internal token exchange become an SAS feature?

Comment: @santos I cannot say for sure that it would *never* be a SAS feature. However, SAS is a framework for providing implementations of OAuth2 specifications. The feature you're describing would be a very valuable feature, but is not detailed in the token exchange specification. Therefore, it needs to be implemented as a product feature in your own AS product. Why? Think about how specific knowledge of each token and each provider is needed for this feature to work. Products would differentiate themselves based on how many providers they integrate with, but SAS is a framework not a product.

Comment: OK, but RFC 8693 states that "Token exchange can work with both tokens issued by other parties and tokens from the given authorization server", referring, wrt the former case, to urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt as the token type id to use ("perhaps in a cross-domain use case where the JWT is used as an authorization grant to obtain an access token from a different authorization server").

Based on this, SAS, as a framework, could support this scenario, right? Or perhaps it already does after all? The developer would ofc fill in the gaps i.e. the specific knowledge that you mentioned.